# How to POST URL in data of a curl request

Tags: linux, web-services, bash, curl, http-post

I am trying to post two parameters using `curl`, `path` and `fileName`:

```
curl --request POST 'http://localhost/Service' --data "path='/xyz/pqr/test/'&fileName='1.doc'"
```

I know something is wrong in this.
I have to use something like URLEncode. I tried many things still no luck.

Please give an example how can I post the url in data of curl request.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Perhaps you don't have to include the single quotes:

```
curl --request POST 'http://localhost/Service' --data "path=/xyz/pqr/test/&fileName=1.doc"
```

Update: Reading curl's manual, you could actually separate both fields with two --data:

```
curl --request POST 'http://localhost/Service' --data "path=/xyz/pqr/test/" --data "fileName=1.doc"
```

You could also try --data-binary:

```
curl --request POST 'http://localhost/Service' --data-binary "path=/xyz/pqr/test/" --data-binary "fileName=1.doc"
```

And --data-urlencode:

```
curl --request POST 'http://localhost/Service' --data-urlencode "path=/xyz/pqr/test/" --data-urlencode "fileName=1.doc"
```

Comment: after & fileName not posted

Comment: how about `data-urlencode` with multiple parameter  _(username, password)_ @konsolebox ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's necessary to use semi-quotes around the variables, try:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost/Service' -d "path=%2fxyz%2fpqr%2ftest%2f&fileName=1.doc"
```

`%2f` is the escape code for a `/`.

http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html

Also, do you need to specify a port? ( just checking :) )

Comment: after & fileName is not posted