# What means data-urlencode in CURL?

Tags: php, curl

I have searched many hours trying to figure out what --data-urlencode is in php curl.

I tried this, but I dont think its right.

```
$xmlpost .= "object1[file]=@https://www.lob.com/goblue.pdf";
```

In the documentation it is:

```
--data-urlencode "object1[file]=https://xxx.pdf" \
```

But what is it in CURL? 
    `curl_setopt($cpt, CURLOPT_??)`

Full API DOCS says i need to call this

```
curl https://api.lob.com/v1/jobs \
-u test_0dc8d51e0acffcb1880e0f19c79b2f5b0cc: \
-d "name=Demo Quick Print Job" \
-d "to[name]=Harry Zhang" \
-d "to[address_line1]=123 Test Street" \
-d "to[address_city]=Mountain View" \
-d "to[address_state]=CA" \
-d "to[address_zip]=94085" \
-d "to[address_country]=US" \
-d "from[name]=Leore Avidar" \
-d "from[address_line1]=123 Test Street." \
-d "from[address_line2]=Apt 155" \
-d "from[address_city]=Sunnyvale" \
-d "from[address_state]=CA" \
-d "from[address_zip]=94085" \
-d "from[address_country]=US" \
-d "object1[name]=testobject" \
--data-urlencode "object1[file]=https://www.lob.com/goblue.pdf" \
-d "object1[setting_id]=100"
```

I am therefore trying:

```
<?php
 $xmlpost = array(
    "name" => "PostalAddressConfirmation",
    "to" => array(
        "name" => "Testing",
        "address_line1" => "testvej",
        "address_city" => "test",
        "address_state" => "test",
        "address_zip" => "5000",
        "address_country" => "DK"
    ),
    "from" => array(
        "name" => "test ApS",
        "address_line1" => "testvej 25",
        "address_city" => "test",
        "address_state" => "test",
        "address_zip" => "5000",
        "address_country" => "DK"
    ),
    "object1" => array(
        "name" => "test Object",
        "setting_id" => "100",
        "file" => "https://lob.com/goblue.pdf"
    )
);

$cpt = curl_init("https://api.lob.com/v1/job");
curl_setopt_array($cpt, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $xmlpost,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'test_0dc8d51e0acffcb1880e0f19c79b2f5b0cc:',
));

$result = curl_exec($cpt);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that you don't even need to think about it; consider the following code:

```
$xmlpost  = [
    "name" => "PostalAddressConfirmation",

    // Lav modtager
    "to" => [
        "name" => "Jespern",
        "address_line1" => "hejvej",
        "address_city" => "Odense",
        "address_state" => "Syddanmark",
        // etc ...
    ],

    // Lav afsender
    "from" => [
        "name" => "test",
        // etc.
    ],

    //Dokument der skal sendes
    "object1" => [
        "name" => "AddressConfirmation",
        "setting_id" => 100,
        "file" => "https://www.lob.com/goblue.pdf",
        "quantity" => 1,
    ],
];

$cpt = curl_init("https://api.lob.com/v1/job");
curl_setopt_array($cpt, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'test_0dc8d51e0acffcb1880e0f19c79b2f5b0cc:',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($xmlpost),
]);

$result = curl_exec($cpt);
```

The [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query) function will build the appropriate string to post.

Comment: @user3195288 I forgot to use the `http_build_query()` function, updated answer.

Comment: Still not working, wierd. Have you readed this? https://www.lob.com/ under "An intuitive RESTful API"

Comment: @user3195288 For one, you forgot to copy `'quantity' > 1,`.

Comment: Well, add debugging and see where it goes wrong; can't help much there.

Answer (score 8):

From the man page you get

> **--data-urlencode `<data>`**
>
> (HTTP) This posts data, similar to the other --data options with the
>   exception that this performs URL-encoding.

For information the `--data` option is described as follow :

> **-d, --data `<data>`**
>
> This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the
>   content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: I know, but how does the php look like, when i will make that kind of command? curl_setopt(???) or?

Comment: did you see the sub-section about `name@filename`

Comment: This thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/18204505/802365 separate `path` and `filename` in two `--data`

Comment: Check my question again.

Answer (score 5):

The data you send to the server MUST already be properly encoded, curl will not do that for you. For example, if you want the data to contain a space, you need to replace that space with %20 etc.

```
 curl --data "birthyear=1905&press=%20OK%20"
```

Failing to comply with this will most likely cause your data to be received wrongly and messed up.

Recent curl versions can in fact url-encode POST data for you, like this:

```
 curl --data-urlencode "name=I am Daniel"
```

reference: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$cpt = curl_init("https://api.lob.com/v1/jobs/job_d36e1e8dd601a777");
curl_setopt_array($cpt,[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,CURLOPT_USERPWD=>'test_b0e6bdb01af4b752ea2f688cce161512f12f44',]);
        $result = curl_exec($cpt);

print_r($result);
```

Guys, You can use this code for getting jobs listing.

Working perfectly fine for me.