# How to convert a curl containing --data-urlencode to a HttpClient call?

Tags: c#, curl, post, .net-core

I am wondering how to convert that curl call below to a .NET Core `HttpClient` call in C#:

```
curl -X POST \
    -d "client_id=client-id-source" \
    -d "audience=client-id-target" \
    -d "subject_token=access-token-goes-here" \
    --data-urlencode "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange" \
    --data-urlencode "requested_token_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:access_token" \
    https://auth-dom/auth/realms/that-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

So far I drafter something like:

```
public static class MultipartFormDataContentExtensions
{
    public static void AddStringContent(this MultipartFormDataContent content, string name, string value)
    {
        content.Add(new StringContent(value), name);
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(params string[] args)
    {
        const string url = "https://auth-dom/auth/realms/that-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token";

        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        content.AddStringContent("client_id", "client-id-source");
        content.AddStringContent("audience", "client-id-source");
        content.AddStringContent("subject_token", "access-token-goes-here");

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how `--data-urlencode` are converted in the request, any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That answer there helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21989124/4636721

I ended up just using a plain `FormUrlEncodedContent` as content:

const string url = "https://auth-dom/auth/realms/that-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token";

```cs
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("subject_token", "access-token-goes-here"),

    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "client-id-source"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("audience", "client-id-target"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "client-id-source"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("requested_token_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:access_token")
});

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
```

And it works just fine.